# Workbox's service worker not updating when changed

Tags: service-worker, workbox

### Explanation

I'm having an issue with [Workbox](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/) where my website doesn't update when a file's content is changed, unless I manually clear storage/site data in my browser.

Since v4 release this year, the [cleanupOutdatedCaches](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-precaching#clean_up_old_precaches), which is in my code, should take care of this, but the problem persists.

### Example

I created [this website](https://workbox-sw.netlify.com/) to exemplify. Once you access it, Workbox will install the service worker, but if I change, for example, `test1` to `test2`, you won't see the change, unless you clear the site data in your browser and refresh.

I also tried only unregistering the sw; it shows the updated version (test2), but when refreshing twice it goes back to the old version (test1).

You can see the website's code in GitHub [here](https://github.com/projectssome/test).

Thanks in advance, 
Luiz.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*cleanOutdatedCaches* will only clean caches created by older versions of the workbox library. In this case, since you are using the same version fo workbox, the call to this method does nothing.

https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/reference-docs/latest/workbox.precaching#.cleanupOutdatedCaches

Once a particular file is precached by Workbox, it will never attempt to retrieve that file from the network, unless the revision you have specified in the *precacheAndRoute* call is different from what was previously cached.

Since you changed index.html but not the revision in *precacheAndRoute*, workbox assumes the file is unchanged. So,what you need to do is to update the *precacheAndRoute* with a new hash that corresponds to the new version of index.html

You can achieve this by either using injectManifest
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-build

or any other build tooling you use.

Edit:

You can invoke skipWaiting programmatically as well
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-core#skip_waiting_and_clients_claim

But you do need to use it with caution. Here is one way to do it : 
https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes

Comment: Thanks for answering! I was using `injectManifest` already, but I tested it again. I changed `test1` to `test5` in index.html and `injectManifest` provided a new hash as you can see [here](https://github.com/projectssome/test/commit/3ed0c436c9790045ba1585f26cd2991398e3afd7#diff-36a6321ccec60e74fcb19c8b57d29b8d), but even after refreshing the page, the old version (test1) remains.

Comment: I also noticed that `skipWaiting` showed up and after skipping, the page updated, but I can't expect users to do it

Comment: You can invoke skipWaiting programmatically  as well:  https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-core#skip_waiting_and_clients_claim . But you do need to use it with caution. Here is one way to do it : https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/guides/advanced-recipes

Comment: That works! I mean, the user still needs to refresh the page, but I've been reading about it and I can make it easier by using [workbox-window](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/workbox/modules/workbox-window). By the way, thanks!!

Comment: If possible, edit your answer with this last comment of yours, please.